# Process recognition tool for macOS to remove unnecessary processes

Tags: macos, software-recommendation

I have a gazillion (408 atm) processes running on my Macbook Pro. I'm running MacOs High Sierra 10.13.6. The system isn't slow and I understand that many of them are necessary, but I think the number could be a bit smaller. Is there any tool, app or even process database that can give me info like:

- `fontd` - font caching and verification, system installed, don't touch except sth...
- `Spotify` - music player for the streaming platform, installed by user, can disable
- `Some random thing` - unknown crap, installed by user, uninstall ASAP

With a list like this, I could decrapify my system a bit.

Comment: This is not something feasible.  There's virtually a limitless plethora  of 3rd party applications; none of which are required to be "registered" with anyone so a centralized "app repository" simply cannot be comprehensive.  Also, this is something that is contrary to the philosophy of Apple.  Please remember, macOS ≠ Linux

Comment: What exactly do You mean by "philosophy of Apple"?

Comment: Apple's philosophy is "it just works" meaning, whatever you want to do, the "Mac" will do it, no drivers required.  This means daemons running in the background, ready to go to work.  Removing them breaks things and everything you remove can/will be re-enabled on the next update.